# CMake. Linker error when compiling shared library. Linux - Ubuntu

Tags: cmake

I try to build my library as shared on Ubuntu using CMake and GCC(G++), but I get linker error every time. But when I compile my library as static it builds well. Also, when I build it on Windows it compiles well as Shared and as Static library also.

Linker error looks like that:

```
usr/bin/ld: Dependencies/GLAD/libGLAD.a(gl.c.o): warning: relocation against glad_glNamedFramebufferReadBuffer&apos; in read-only section .text&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Soul-Byte-Engine-Core-Window-Manager-obj.dir/Sources/WindowManager.cpp.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZSt4cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4&apos; can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Soul-Byte-Engine-Core-Window-Manager.dir/build.make:89: libSoul-Byte-Engine-Core-Window-Manager.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:164: CMakeFiles/Soul-Byte-Engine-Core-Window-Manager.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

`CMakeLists.txt` what I wrote looks like that:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)



project(Soul-Byte-Engine-Core-Window-Manager VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)



option(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_AS_STATIC "" OFF)

option(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_WITH_GLFW_SOURCES "" OFF)

option(INCLUDE_LOGGING_SYSTEM_SUPPORT "" OFF)



string(TIMESTAMP BuildDate "%Y-%m-%d")



set(BUILT_BY "Unknown" CACHE STRING "The name of build author")



get_directory_property(hasParent PARENT_DIRECTORY)



if(hasParent)

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_MAJOR_VERSION  PARENT_SCOPE)

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_MINOR_VERSION  PARENT_SCOPE)

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_PATCH_VERSION  PARENT_SCOPE)

else()

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_MAJOR_VERSION 1)

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_MINOR_VERSION 0)

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_PATCH_VERSION 0)

endif()







include_directories(Include)



add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-obj

    OBJECT 

    Sources/WindowManager.cpp

    Sources/META.cpp

    Include/WindowManager/WindowManager.hpp

    Include/WindowManager/META.hpp

)





add_subdirectory(Dependencies/GLAD)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-obj PUBLIC Dependencies/GLAD/include)



if(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_AS_STATIC)

    

    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} 

        STATIC 

        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-obj>

    )



else()

    if(WIN32)

        set ( CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

    endif()

    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}

        SHARED

        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-obj>

    )



endif()







if(WIN32)

    if(NOT BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_WITH_GLFW_SOURCES)

        message(WARNING "When using Windows OS Window Manager will be built with GLFW sources regardless of options !")

        set(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_WITH_GLFW_SOURCES ON)

    endif()

endif()





if(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_WITH_GLFW_SOURCES)

    set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

    set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

    set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

    set(GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

    add_subdirectory(Dependencies/GLFW)

    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-obj PUBLIC Dependencies/GLFW/include)

else()

    find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-obj PUBLIC ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

endif()



include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/META)



if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)

    set(BUILT_FOR "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} x86_64")

elseif(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)

    set(BUILT_FOR "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} x86")

endif()



configure_file(

    "META/BuildInfo.h.in"

    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/META/BuildInfo.h"

)





target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GLAD glfw)
```

Git Repo with Source code: https://github.com/sp1cklerBoy/Soul-Byte-Engine-Core/tree/main

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed it. I just added compiler -fPIC flag using cmake add_definitions() function.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)



project(Soul-Byte-Engine-Core-Window-Manager VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)



SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-fPIC")

 add_definitions(${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS})



option(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_AS_STATIC "" OFF)

option(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_WITH_GLFW_SOURCES "" OFF)

option(INCLUDE_LOGGING_SYSTEM_SUPPORT "" OFF)



string(TIMESTAMP BuildDate "%Y-%m-%d")







set(BUILT_BY "Unknown" CACHE STRING "The name of build author")



get_directory_property(hasParent PARENT_DIRECTORY)



if(hasParent)

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_MAJOR_VERSION  PARENT_SCOPE)

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_MINOR_VERSION  PARENT_SCOPE)

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_PATCH_VERSION  PARENT_SCOPE)

else()

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_MAJOR_VERSION 1)

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_MINOR_VERSION 0)

    set(WINDOW_MANAGER_PATCH_VERSION 0)

endif()







include_directories(Include)



add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-obj

    OBJECT 

    Sources/WindowManager.cpp

    Sources/META.cpp

    Include/WindowManager/WindowManager.hpp

    Include/WindowManager/META.hpp

)





add_subdirectory(Dependencies/GLAD)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-obj PUBLIC Dependencies/GLAD/include)



if(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_AS_STATIC)

    

    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} 

        STATIC 

        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-obj>

    )



else()

    if(WIN32)

        set ( CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

    endif()

    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}

        SHARED

        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-obj>

    )



endif()







if(WIN32)

    if(NOT BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_WITH_GLFW_SOURCES)

        message(WARNING "When using Windows OS Window Manager will be built with GLFW sources regardless of options !")

        set(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_WITH_GLFW_SOURCES ON)

    endif()

endif()





if(BUILD_WINDOW_MANAGER_WITH_GLFW_SOURCES)

    set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

    set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

    set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

    set(GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

    add_subdirectory(Dependencies/GLFW)

    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-obj PUBLIC Dependencies/GLFW/include)

else()

    find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-obj PUBLIC ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

endif()



include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/META)



if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)

    set(BUILT_FOR "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} x86_64")

elseif(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)

    set(BUILT_FOR "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} x86")

endif()



configure_file(

    "META/BuildInfo.h.in"

    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/META/BuildInfo.h"

)





target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GLAD glfw)
```